# Get selected item from asp.net menu control in code behind

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

On a post back i cannot seem to get the selected menu item from the menu control in the MasterPage. I tried the following in page_load but it does not work and errors out 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

Html in the MasterPage

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
       IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
       <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" />
           <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About" />
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx" Text="Contact" />
       </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

Page_Load in the MasterPage

```
 If IsPostBack Then
   Select Case NavigationMenu.SelectedItem.Text
        Case "Home"
            'code
        Case "About"
            'code
        Case "Contact"
            'code
   End Select
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MenuItemClick event. If NavigateUrl property is null "", then the click event fires, if you have either "#" or a url to another page then the click event does not work. [Reference article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1672161.aspx/1)

```
  Protected Sub NavigationMenu_MenuItemClick(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs) Handles NavigationMenu.MenuItemClick
    Select Case e.Item.Text
        Case "Home"
            'code
        Case "About"
            'code
        Case "Contact"
            'code
    End Select
  End Sub
```

Event will fire...

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="" Text="Home" />
```

Event will not fire...

```
<asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About" />
```

Note:
I ended up using an Unordered List instead with Javascript postback to server side events. The asp.net MenuControl was not flexible enough for my situation.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting your code inside if (!IsPostBack) { //Code here } in the page_load.

Comment: In masterpage codebehind it never goes through the postback. i updated the code.

Comment: In NavigationMenu.SelectedItem it will erase the value on each postback. Make sure its value is not erased on NavigationMenu.SelectedItem by binding the NavigationMenu values inside if(!IsPostBack) in the page_load.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would bind items when the values are done at design time and not databound.